# A way to get from music player back to artist selection

Tags: music, zune-player

I have some music playing on the phone. I want to change the artist. I press the volume button, this brings the music player popup. I tap on the song title. This brings the "whole-screen" player with album art, some play buttons, artist name and song title and playlist. Then I tap on artist name. This bring pivot screen with artist related lists - albums list and songs list.

What should I tap now to get to another artist / to list of artists?

(I know I can get there through my main screen -> music+video tile -> music link. I want to know if there is "back-track")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the shortcut only gets you to the current artist related songs or albums. Only access to the music + video hub from the home screen will get you a list of all the songs and albums on your phone.

Comment: Was afraid of that :)